# Prove a function is onto and find the inverse of the equation?

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is: Let $X = [0,\infty)$ and $Y =[0,1)$. Define $f:X\mapsto Y$ by $f(x) = \frac x{x+3}$. Show that $f$ is onto and find the equation of the inverse $f^{-1}:Y\mapsto X$.

I understand the basic definitions of why a function is onto, but not sure how to go about a proof and work around the ranges of $X$ and $Y$.

I know a function is onto where $f:A\mapsto B$ if $B = \text{rng}(f)$ but not sure at all in how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $\text{rng}(f)=X$ is to show that, for any $y\in Y$, there is at least one $x\in X$ which satisfies $f(x)=y$, which is in your case $\frac{x}{x+3}=y$. So, you think of $y\in Y$ fixed, and you solve the equation $\frac{x}{x+3}=y$ for $x$. That's a way to prove that the function is onto.

Comment: So what i assume you mean by the is get x by itself, which is the same as finding the inverse, correct?

Comment: Do I then have to provide examples of x where Y is in the range [0,1)

Comment: Yes it's like if you're trying to find the inverse. Nah don't use examples, because examples are specific case. Since you want to prove that it works for **any** $y\in Y$, you have to solve the equation $\frac{x}{x+3}=y$ for the unknown $x$. See $y$ like if it was given a value. **Hint:** it's the same as solving $x=(x+3)y$ (because $x\in X$, you have $x\neq -3$).

Comment: I found the inverse to be x = -3y / y-1 ( I needed it for part 2 of the problem i think anyways).  When Y is in the range [0,1), X will be located in its given range [0,infinity). Does that seem correct?

Comment: @user604296 Yes that's correct! Well done!

Comment: @user604296 As you're new to this site, if you found my answer useful, please don't forget to upvote it and accept it as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help!.

Comment: @user604296 It's a pleasure :)